# Get back the row names using a loop

Tags: r, loops

I write some code to get back the row.names of a clustering result going from 1 to 16. That's working but that's a lot of lines as you can see :

```
Factor1 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 1))
Factor2 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 2))
Factor3 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 3))
Factor4 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 4))
Factor5 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 5))
Factor6 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 6))
Factor7 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 7))
Factor8 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 8))
Factor9 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 9))
Factor10 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 10))
Factor11 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 11))
Factor12 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 12))
Factor13 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 13))
Factor14 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 14))
Factor15 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 15))
Factor16 <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == 16))
```

So, I just write my very first loop to reduce the number of lines and optimize the code but sadly that's not working.

```
Factor=NULL

for(i in 1:16) {
  Factor[i] <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == i))
}
```

Can someone point out the mistake I made ?

Comment: You may be under the incorrect impression that you would get a set of FactorNN's but that code should only produce one item named `Factor` with 16 values. It should be "working" but perhaps not the way you expected.

Comment: Thanks again akrun. But I do need each each factor alone. It will not be more efficient if I have to extract each element of the list 16 times using [[]] isnt'it ?

Comment: @ePoQ Do you mean you want to create 16 `Factor` objects?  It would clutter the environment.  You could perhaps all the necessary analysis in the list itself.  I updated the post.

Comment: You were close...
    assign(paste0("Factor", i), row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17 == i)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  lst1  <- lapply(1:16, function(i) row.names(subset(res.uc.df, uc.seed17==i)))
```

Or using your code

```
 lst2 <- list()
 for(i in 1:16){
    lst2[[i]] <- row.names(subset(res.uc.df,uc.seed17==i))
  }

 identical(lst1, lst2)
 #[1] TRUE
```

If you want to create 16 `Factor` objects

```
 list2env(setNames(lst1, paste0("Factor", seq_along(lst1))), envir=.GlobalEnv)
 # <environment: R_GlobalEnv>

 Factor1
 #[1] "35" "37" "43"

 Factor16
 #[1] "16" "17" "23" "24" "44" "46" "49"
```

#### data

```
 set.seed(42)
 res.uc.df <- data.frame(uc.seed17=sample(1:16,50,replace=TRUE), val=rnorm(50))
```

Comment: and again you save me. list2env is very usefull. Thanks